# MVC 5 - Default Area Route - Id parameter mistaken by Action name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I've read all the questions in Stackoverflow that I could find about this subject that were not so old, and till now I haven't find a solution to my simple case.

I just created 2 controllers in an Area, and I am using the default auto generated area routes.

When I try to access by:

http://localhost:57969/FieldProduction/CustomerProduction/1

I have an exception and with the help of Glimpse information I see that the "1" is been interpreted as the action and not as a parameter....

[image]

I When I try to access one of the area controllers with:

http://localhost:57969/FieldProduction/CustomerProduction/?1

The default action "Index" is used, but the contructor variable int? Id is not beeing filled.

[image]

**Action:**

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int? id)
```

**Default Area Controller Route:**

```
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "FieldProduction_default",
            "FieldProduction/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }                
        );
    }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a entry in the route for the controller!?  controller="XXX"

Comment: Your route has 4 segments - the 2nd is the controller name and the 3rd is the action name. Your url has 3 segments - `FieldProduction/CustomerProduction/1` - the 3rd segment (for the action name) is `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am leaving this question open in order for possible other solutions, but at the moment I was able to solve my problem by writing a custom route in the areaRegistration

```
        //**NEW ROUTE**
        context.MapRoute(
            "FieldProduction_CustomerProduction",
            "FieldProduction/CustomerProduction/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", controller = "CustomerProduction", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        //**ORIGINAL ROUTE**
        context.MapRoute(
            "FieldProduction_default",
            "FieldProduction/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }                
        );
```

Comment: What will happen if You try to call action without Id parameter? 
example: FieldProduction/CustomerProduction/actionName 
Maybe it will try to map actionName to id?

Comment: This is the right answer. The reason why it thought the `1` is your `action` name is because you passed it as the 3rd segment. Segments don't change position in the URL (whether or not they are optional) - if you define `{action}` as the 3rd segment you must pass an `action` name that MVC will understand in the 3rd segment. You can leave action name out of the URL as above, but this limits the route so it only works on this one action method (`Index`). If you want to call other action methods in the controller, you must explicitly pass the action or else define additional routes.

Answer (score 0):

Your routing thinks that /1 is action name (but You know this)
You have two options: 
1st one:  add id parameter like this:

> http://localhost:57969/FieldProduction/CustomerProduction?id=1

2nd: Use attribute routing in this controller.

[attribute routing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)

There is 3rd option, You can add regex to Your routing, to identifiy that action is never int.